# Web scraping with selenium python with captcha

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha

I am trying to web scrap this website https://parade.com/968666/parade/chuck-norris-jokes/ to get the 101 jokes. It is just for practice. I get blocked even after manualy solving the captcha. I have my captcha api key. How can I find the captcha_input? What is the best way to make it happen?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a captcha on that page?

Comment: When I am trying to scrap there is. If you just open the website you won't see it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the user agent string? There isn't enough information in your question to give an answer really. If you can add your code then we have more to go on.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I am scraping the page with selenium and there is a captcha that is blocking me for some reason. With Beatingsoup I get error that Javascript is blocked. Checked my Chrome it is not blocked. Can add my code tomorrow

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve], then edit your question to include all relevant details. Right now it's a link to a site and something about you being blocked. And no, nobody should be opening the web site to understand your question.